# How To Creating A Component That Works With StackNavigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a global Navigation Bar that gets included into "Screen" files. I am fairly new to React Native and the issue I am having is that I am also trying to use StackNavigator within the included Nav Bar. By doing this I am getting the following error.

[image]

I am using the following code.

```
import NavBar from "../../components/navBar";


export default class HomeView extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home Screen',
    headerVisible: false,
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.contentWrapper}>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <NavBar />
        <View style={styles.boxTop}><Text>Test</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.boxBottom}><Text>Test</Text></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And in the nav file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image
} from 'react-native'


export default class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.contentWrapper}>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  contentWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    height: 40,
  },
});
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to create the component and include the StackNavigator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just about got it! The `navigation` prop is available only to screens that are directly passed to a StackNavigator (or other navigator). There's two ways you can get access to `navigation` from your Navbar component.

The first way would be to pass the navigation prop to your Navbar component whenever you use it, like this.

```
import NavBar from "../../components/navBar";


export default class HomeView extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home Screen',
    headerVisible: false,
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.contentWrapper}>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <NavBar navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        <View style={styles.boxTop}><Text>Test</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.boxBottom}><Text>Test</Text></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

or you can use the higher order component `withNavigation` to wrap your Navbar and have access to navigation but you don't need to remember to pass it as a prop each time you use the Navbar component. That would look like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image
} from 'react-native'
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.contentWrapper}>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  contentWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    height: 40,
  },
});

export default withNavigation(Navbar);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I will try that now.